# Workaround for dependency property value precendence

Tags: wpf

I'm builiding a custom control as seen below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.Views.Components.MenuButton"
    [...]>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:MenuButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding HoverForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding HoverBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

The said control has 2 dependency properties: HoverForeground and HoverBackground, why did I define them? - So I can have infinite amount of buttons with relatively easy to set hover color.

The issue is, I can't walk around DPVP and whenever I set Foreground in another control (as seen below), the foreground will no longer change upon IsMouseOver event.

Here's the code for another control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.Views.Components.Menu"
    [...]>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <local:MenuButton Foreground="{DynamicResource BackgroundDark}" HoverForeground="Red" HoverBackground="Red" Margin="8" Content="" FontSize="24"/>
        <local:MenuButton Foreground="{DynamicResource BackgroundDark}" HoverForeground="Green" HoverBackground="Green" Margin="8" Content="" FontSize="24"/>
        <local:MenuButton Foreground="{DynamicResource BackgroundDark}" HoverForeground="Blue" HoverBackground="Blue" Margin="8" Content="" FontSize="24"/>
        <local:MenuButton Foreground="{DynamicResource BackgroundDark}" HoverForeground="Black" HoverBackground="Yellow" Margin="8" Content="" FontSize="24"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

I read your question and, if I understood it right, setting the `Foreground` on your controls overrides the changes you make through your control's `Style` triggers to that same property.

I would't recommend you to use triggers that change properties on your control, specially common properties like `Background` and `Foreground`. Your control's properties are intended to be set by the consumer of your control from the outside of your code. If you use a `Style` and use triggers on it that change properties on the control in response to certain events, that may be unexpected to the consumer of your control and is overriden when the consumer sets those same properties explicitly. The only properties you should be changing dynamically on your control are the read-only ones.

A better approach (and also the intended one) to dynamicaly change the appearance of your control during its lifetime, is to use a `ControlTemplate`. Control templates don't change properties on your control; instead, they change properties on their own elements, which they use to draw the control's visual. For example, you could use a `Trigger` on your `ControlTemplate` that changes the brushes of some visual element when the mouse is over the control, in a similar fashion to what you've done on the `Style`'s triggers. Nobody has access to the element you are changing the brush, except you, so you are free to change what you want on it whenever you want.

This example, should give you an idea of how to create a `Style` that sets a `ControlTemplate` for your control. I've just written the code in a rush, without testing it, so it could be some typo or something:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuButton">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#282828"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#D0D0D0"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuButton}">
        <Border x:Name="TemplateRoot"
                Background="{TemplateBinding HoverBackground}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignement="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignement}"
                            VerticalAlignement="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignement}"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="TemplateRoot" Property="Background" 
                    Value="{Binding HoverBackground, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="TextElement.Foreground" 
                    Value="{Binding HoverForeground, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Some things to note about the `ControlTemplate` is that it uses mostly `TemplateBinding` extensions to bind to properties of the templated control, instead of the usual `Binding`, although this last would be fine as well. When using `Binding`, you refer to the templated control using a `RelativeSource` source with `TemplatedParent` mode. For example:

```
{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}
```

But using `TemplateBinding`, where it can be used, is just more convenient. So the binding above could be written like this:

```
{TemplateBinding Background}
```

The understandable negative side of setting a custom `ControlTemplate` to a control is that we need to write it from scratch, which is a pain, some of the times. This is specially true for complex controls. When we just need to change a few things on the visual, it seems tempting to do it directly on the control's `Style`, like you're doing. However, I recommend against that practice, as it tends to create more problems than it solves.

---

`Style` and `ControlTemplate` have names that are somewhat misleading. Basically, they are both intended to do something to controls in a reusable manner in your application. In short, when you want to set something related to the appearance of a control and that is to be reusable, you should use a `ControlTemplate`.

The `Style` is intended to be used for setting the default values of your control's properties. The triggers of a `Style` are no exception to that; they are intended to set default values to properties of the control, but they have the ability to do it based on some condition. For example, a `TabControl` may need to use triggers on its `Style` to set the value of its `Template` property depending on the value of `TabStripPlacement`, so the control automatically switches templates depending whether the tabs are placed on the left, top, right or bottom.